# SQL Server query with CASE and GROUP BY, field invalid?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. It says field HasNoteDate is invalid. I just want it to return 1 if there's a date, 0 if there's not and I wanted it grouped so I can get the counts and the sum of loan amounts. I've looked at the stackoverflow answers for grouping by a case and none of them are solving it for me. Thanks!

```
SELECT    dbo.BDONAMES.UserID, dbo.BRKRMAST.Tier, dbo.BDONAMES.REGION, COUNT(*) AS TierRegionCount, 
                      SUM(dbo.LOAN.LOAN_AMT) AS LoanAmtSum, dbo.LOAN.DEAL_STATUS, CASE WHEN dbo.WORKFLOW.NOTE_DATE IS NULL 
                      THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasNoteDate
FROM         dbo.BRKRMAST INNER JOIN
                      dbo.BRKRREF ON dbo.BRKRMAST.BRKRMASTID = dbo.BRKRREF.BRKRMASTID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.LOAN ON dbo.BRKRREF.LoanId = dbo.LOAN.LoanId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.WORKFLOW ON dbo.LOAN.LoanId = dbo.WORKFLOW.LoanId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.BDONAMES ON dbo.BRKRMAST.BDONAMESID = dbo.BDONAMES.BDONAMESID
WHERE     (LEN(dbo.BDONAMES.UserID) > 0) AND (dbo.BRKRMAST.Tier > 0) AND (LEN(dbo.BDONAMES.REGION) > 0)
GROUP BY dbo.BDONAMES.UserID, dbo.BRKRMAST.Tier, dbo.BDONAMES.REGION, dbo.LOAN.LOAN_AMT, dbo.LOAN.DEAL_STATUS, HasNoteDate
ORDER BY dbo.BDONAMES.UserID, dbo.BRKRMAST.Tier, dbo.BDONAMES.REGION
```

Comment: Have you tried ordering by `SUM(dbo.LOAN.LOAN_AMT) AS LoanAmtSum` instead of `dbo.LOAN.LOAN_AMT`?

Comment: in `group by` try to change `HasNoteDate` to `(CASE WHEN dbo.WORKFLOW.NOTE_DATE IS NULL 
                      THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`

Comment: That was it @IlyaBursov, want to answer it?

Comment: @DontFretBrett ok, will provide descriptive answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logic of SQL query execution is not straightforward as common programming languages

here are sample execution stages for your query:

1. perform join on tables in `FROM CLAUSE`
2. perform `GROUP BY` - this will cause error, as `HasNoteDate` is not defined for this moment
3. perform `ORDER BY`
4. perform `SELECT` - only during this stage column `HasNoteDate` is defined

so, you cannot use undefined column `HasNoteDate` in GROUP BY, you have to replace it with your statement `(CASE WHEN dbo.WORKFLOW.NOTE_DATE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`, then sql server will be able to `GROUP`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    dbo.BDONAMES.UserID, dbo.BRKRMAST.Tier, dbo.BDONAMES.REGION, COUNT(*) AS TierRegionCount, 
                      SUM(dbo.LOAN.LOAN_AMT) AS LoanAmtSum, dbo.LOAN.DEAL_STATUS, CASE WHEN dbo.WORKFLOW.NOTE_DATE IS NULL 
                      THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasNoteDate
FROM         dbo.BRKRMAST INNER JOIN
                      dbo.BRKRREF ON dbo.BRKRMAST.BRKRMASTID = dbo.BRKRREF.BRKRMASTID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.LOAN ON dbo.BRKRREF.LoanId = dbo.LOAN.LoanId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.WORKFLOW ON dbo.LOAN.LoanId = dbo.WORKFLOW.LoanId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.BDONAMES ON dbo.BRKRMAST.BDONAMESID = dbo.BDONAMES.BDONAMESID
WHERE     (LEN(dbo.BDONAMES.UserID) > 0) AND (dbo.BRKRMAST.Tier > 0) AND (LEN(dbo.BDONAMES.REGION) > 0)
GROUP BY dbo.BDONAMES.UserID, dbo.BRKRMAST.Tier, dbo.BDONAMES.REGION, dbo.LOAN.DEAL_STATUS, CASE WHEN dbo.WORKFLOW.NOTE_DATE IS NULL 
                                                                                                        THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
ORDER BY dbo.BDONAMES.UserID, dbo.BRKRMAST.Tier, dbo.BDONAMES.REGION
```

Use columns in your group by exactly the way you have defined in you select Statement, otherwise SQL server tries to GROUP it with the fields that it cannot find in SELECT statement and throws an error.